# Selecting a folder in a drilldown / column view

Tags: mobile, navigation, drilldown

In my web app, I'm looking to allow users to select 'folders' from their filesystem which will then be stored and scanned to build a library of media files. But I'm having trouble designing an intuitive interface for selecting folders.

My initial thought was to have an iOS-like drill-down list that would allow the user to navigate their file-system, and select the folder when they find it. But in this case, I need to disambiguate between *opening the folder* and *selecting the folder*. I can't find an intuitive way of doing this. I've considered having checkboxes next to each folder... or having a 'select' button next to each... or requiring a double-click to open the folder... but these don't seem ideal.

Any suggestions for this? I'd like it to be touch/mobile friendly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I've seen is to simply have a checkbox next to the folder name, like in Google Drive:
[image: Google Drive]

Comment: I think you're probably right. The checkbox isn't all that mobile friendly, but I think you can emulate the behaviour with enlarged widgets.

Comment: There are a few options to improve it for mobile – A) you could use a hidden swipe menu for each list item, B) you could simply show the unchecked box, or C) you could use a "tap and hold" interaction to check it (to name a few).